# Convert text with newlines to Java String in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, edit

I have a long SQL statement with lots of linebreaks that I want to put inside my Java code as a `String`. Can I perform that operation automatically with IntelliJ IDEA? If not, is there some other easy way?

For example I want the code

```
 SELECT
    *
 FROM
    MyTable
```

to be converted into

```
 "SELECT\n" +
 "   *\n" +
 "FROM\n" +
 "   MyTable"
```

Comment: In this example, why would you want to add line breaks to your query, which is not necessary?  If you assign your query to a `String` in IntelliJ and press enter after a certain word, the IDE will automatically break the string into a newline (without adding `\n`).

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: The query is written in an SQL tool, so it was copied and pasted from the tool into IntelliJ. I want to avoid pressing Enter for each line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is reall simple!

Just create yourself a code block like this:

```
String sql = "";
```

Situate the cursor -inside- the double quotes and just paste the sql code (containing newlines).

Result will be like this:

```
String sql = " SELECT\n" +
        "    *\n" +
        " FROM\n" +
        "    MyTable";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can inject languages into a String literal, in this case SQL. Then, on the String literal, you can edit in in a special editor which will convert the input into a valid Java String (including the line breaks you mentioned). In your case you can just start with an empty String, and edit/fill it as described.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/using-language-injections.html#d1023038e185

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/opening-language-injections-in-the-editor.html

Comment: Interesting. However, I can't get IntelliJ to recognize the `@Language()` annotation, despite having enabled the IntelliLang plugin. I will try harder.

Comment: The annotation is "just" helpful so that IntelliJ doesn't forget about the language represented in the String. If you don't need to edit the String that often, you can just inject the language when necessary. PS: I'd appreciate an "accepted answer" if applicable.

Comment: It would be nice to have a code snippet in the answer which demonstrates the solution.